# Free software to fill xfa forms in pdf

Tags: pdf, xfa

I have pdf file with XFA forms. I need to populate this pdf with data and send it to user. I am looking for a library will help me in that. This library needs to be:
 - free, meaning that I can use it for free in the proprietary software,
 - written in a language, which can be easily installed on a linux machine (java, python, ruby?)

I was already looking at iText, but its latest LGPL version is quite old and generates broken pdf in my case. What is strange, iTextSharp works for me, but I don't think that it will work on mono.

Reasonably priced paid solutions are also welcomed.

Comment: If the current iText version (in contrast to the ancient latest LGPL version) works for you and you also consider a paid solution, you may want to contact iText sales and ask them for a fair price --- when talking with them directly, they also take the individual circumstances into account which can result in a considerably lower price than the listed one.